# SQL Server: pivoting across multiple colums

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have a serious problem. Say my data is arranged in this format:

```
Name      Businees_unit  Forecast  Upside
Jack.N    India          100       50
Jack.N    China          250       20
```

I have to pivot `Forecast` and `Upside` for `Business_Unit` so the table will look like this

```
Name    Forecast_India    Upside_India      Forecast_China    Upside_China
Jack    100               50                250               20
```

Can this be done in one query?

Its my first entry, so any help is very welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Which RDBMS (SQLServer, Oracle, MySQL etc.) is this?

Answer (score 1):

A generic solution:

```
select name,
       sum(case when Businees_unit = 'India' then Forecast else 0 end) Forecast_India,
       sum(case when Businees_unit = 'India' then Upside else 0 end) Upside_India,
       sum(case when Businees_unit = 'China' then Forecast else 0 end) Forecast_China,
       sum(case when Businees_unit = 'China' then Upside else 0 end) Upside_China
from My_table
group by name
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use self join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT SomeTable.Name, China.Forecast as Forecast_China, China.Upside as Upside_China
, India.Forecast as Forecast_India, India.Upside as Upside_India
FROM SomeTable
inner join SomeTable India on India.Name = SomeTable.Name AND India.Business_unit = 'India'
inner join SomeTable China on China.Name = SomeTable.Name AND China.Business_unit = 'China'
```

Comment: You're returning two identical rows because [Jack.N] appears twice in the table